# How to get "Text Area" attribute value in phtml file?

Tags: magento-1.9

```
Value is showing on front page under custom tab section but bullets or images are not coming.
```

I am using this code in phtml file

code 1:

```
$_product = $this->getProduct();
echo $_product->getData('customattribute');
```

Or Code 2:

```
<?php if($_product->getCustomattribute()!= null){ ?>
       <div class="similarproduct">
       <div class="coloroptions">Color Options : </div>
       <?php echo $_helper->productAttribute($_product, ($_product->getCustomattribute()), 'customattribute') ?></div>
<?php } ?>
```

code 2 : Gives me error 
code 1 : Print every thing except bullets/images just simple text.

Kindly suggest any method .  i follow almost all post related to this..

Answer (score 0):

If you have custom Module for your page, you have to add your attribute to config.xml of this module. This is an example for adding it into cart page:

```
<sales>
  <quote>
    <item>
      <product_attributes>
        <my_attribute/>
      </product_attributes>
    </item>
  </quote>
</sales>
```

I hope that this helps.

Comment: I added a custom tab on view page using local.xml

Answer (score 0):

I finally I got the answer to this question may be it helps some one.

I used this code in my custom phtml file to show custom attribute value in same way as it is entered in product creation time.

Add below code in `customareamaddy.phtml`

```
$productId = Mage::registry('current_product')->getId();
$_product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($productId);
$_helper = $this->helper('catalog/output');
echo $_helper->productAttribute($_product, ($_product->getCustomareamaddy()), 'customareamaddy');
```